# onDependentViewChanged from CoordinatorLayout.Behavior called all the time

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I implemented `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`and overridden `onDependentViewChanged` function but it worries me it fires every couple milliseconds even the scroll view is staying still.

That doesn't change if I return false from `onDependentViewChanged`

I can't find any information on this, but this thing spamming my logs doesn't look like a proper behavior. Will drain the battery.

My simplified layout look like this:

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/ptr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/avatarContainer"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/scrollView"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal|top"
                app:layout_behavior="my.app.behaviors.ProfileAvatarBehavior">

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently I didn't do as stated with returning false.
Key was to return false if no changes are going to be made and not doing anything with view. What I did was resizing some views anyway (even the params were the same) and then returned false. This resulted in chain calls